# Automatically created Excel file

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2014

I have an SSIS package for importing excel files into the database.
In my source folder, I got an automatically created excel file, and I did not create that file. Even after I delete it, the file will be created again, and it shows that my user account is the owner of the file.
I do not know if any process creates the file.

Comment: You haven't asked anything we can help with. You are creating this file somehow.

Comment: How can I know how this file is created automatically and how can I stop creating it?